# Retrieving Instagram comments from multiple media with python

Tags: python, api, comments, instagram

I'm using [this unofficial API](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/blob/master/examples/get_all_comments.py) to retrieve comments under specific media.
I slightly modified the code so I don't have to change the media id each time to get its comments, so my idea was basically to include a list of media like this:

```
media_list = [media_id1, media_id2, ... ]
```

and pass it to a cycle. My final output would be a text file like this:

```
media_id1
username1 comment1
username2 comment2
username3 comment3
media_id2
username1 comment1
...
```

this is how I modified the original code:

```
for i in medialist:
    comments = []
    while has_more_comments:
        _ = API.getMediaComments(i,max_id=max_id)
        #comments' page come from older to newer, lets preserve desc order in full list
        for c in reversed(API.LastJson['comments']):
            comments.append(c)
        has_more_comments = API.LastJson.get('has_more_comments',False)
        #evaluate stop conditions
        if count and len(comments)>=count:
            comments = comments[:count]
            #stop loop
            has_more_comments = False
            print "stopped by count"

        #next page
        if has_more_comments:
            max_id = API.LastJson.get('next_max_id','')
            time.sleep(2)

    for c in comments:
        username = c['user']['username']
        text = c['text']
        user = username.encode('utf-8')
        txt = text.encode('utf-8')
        print (i+"\n"+user+": "+txt+"\n")
```

My problem is that I only get comments from the first media_id in the list, then it gives me empty lists for the other media:

```
1412361909683907264
[{u'status': u'Active', u'user_id': xxx, u'created_at_utc': xxx, u'created_at': xxx, u'bit_flags': 0, u'comment_like_count': 1, u'did_report_as_spam': False, u'user': {u'username': u'xxx', u'profile_pic_url': u'xxx', u'profile_pic_id': u'xxx', u'full_name': u'xxx', u'pk': xxx, u'is_verified': False, u'is_private': True}, u'content_type': u'comment', u'text': u'When you eat pasta remember me \U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f602\U0001f44d\U0001f3fb\U0001f4aa\U0001f3fc', u'pk': xxx, u'type': 0, u'has_liked_comment': False}]
1412360153562726838
[]
1412342538912059069
[]
1412336815465111851
[]
```

Where is the problem? I'm clearly not a programmer, I have very low competences and experience with python and learned it as a hobby so forgive me if I made some evident mistakes that I still can't notice
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set `has_more_comments` back to `True` after the first item in the media list.

`for i in medialist:
    comments = []
    has_more_comments = True
    while has_more_comments:
        ...`

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now!
has_more_comments was set to True outside the loop, so maybe this was the mistake!

Comment: Yepp, that was it!